# How do I ensure that Tornado will only open a websocket with authenticated users?

Tags: websocket, tornado

The Tornado documentation does not comment on any use of the `tornado.web.authenticated` decorator for use with a `WebSocketHandler`.  I only want to grant a websocket connection to authenticated users.

Through testing it does appear that `initialize()` is being called on the `WebSocketHandler` for the GET request at the connection setup handshake. So I could imagine overriding `initialize()` and checking that the user is authenticated in the standard manner by checking if a valid session token is present in the cookie.

But before I go and hand roll this - I wanted to put it out to the community to see if this is the right approach.

1. Is there a simple and fast way to get `WebSocketHandler` to only continue with the handshake to set up the connection - in a similar way that the `tornado.web.authenticated` decorator does?
2. I am surprised that this is not built-in.  Am I missing something about websockets and how to secure them?

---

**Edit:**
See possible answer below by overriding `_execute()` method rather than `initialize()` method.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to override `open()` and call `self.close()` with an error code if the user is not authorized. If you really want to return an HTTP error instead of a websocket error, you can override `prepare()` instead. Overriding either `get()` or `_execute()` is fragile and discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why previous answer was down-voted, but I found it to be a more appropriate answer , rather than overriding open(). By the time open is called already lots of things have happened like protocol upgrade and websocket connection opened. Then closing this again is an additional overhead.

overriding _execute is the correct way to do.
For tornado 4.0+ , you should override get method like this

```
class WbSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
  @tornado.web.asynchronous
  def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if (not self.current_user):
      self.set_status(401)
      self.finish("Unauthorized")
      return
    super(WbSocketHandler, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for answering my own question within an hour of posting ... but I wanted to get the idea below out there.  Very curious if there is a better way as it always makes me nervous when I have to resort to overriding "underscore" methods and writing low level messages on a stream ... but seems to work.

The handler below checks for authentication before continuing on with "_execute()" method (which checks for GET request and continues with handshake logic).

```
import logging

import tornado.escape
import tornado.websocket


class AuthenticatedWebsocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    '''Only allows a request to open a websocket for a valid current user.
       This class assumes that the get_current_user() method is defined
       to check for a valid session id. (see Tornado docs).
    '''
    def _execute(self, *args, **kwds):
        if not self.current_user:
            logging.warn('Unauthorized attempt by {} to open websocket.'
                    .format(self.request.remote_ip))

            self.stream.write(tornado.escape.utf8(
                'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n\r\n'
                'Not authenticated.'))

            self.stream.close()
            return

        super(AuthenticatedWebsocketHandler, self)._execute(*args, **kwds)
```

The reason that `_execute()` needs to be overwritten instead of `initialize()` has to do with the structure of how Tornado is extending `tornado.web.RequestHandler` for `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler`.  There does not seem to be a graceful way to exit the IOloop with the appropriate response otherwise.

Comment: Override open(), and call self.close() if the user is not logged in. You can decide this via cookies. No need to override _execute etc.